# How to show a new screen from menu item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm new to android and trying to find out how to show a new screen when the user clicks something in the menu item.

I'm using ActionbarSherlock and looking at the sample [github-android app](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/mobile/ui/gist/GistsFragment.java#L82).

When the user clicks on an item in the menu, I want to show them a new screen. Github code is doing that like so:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), CreateGistActivity.class), GIST_CREATE);
```

But I've seen some code samples do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity.class);
```

My code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
 ....
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.create) {
        //show createactivity class
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What is the right way to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
 ....
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.create) {
        //show createactivity class
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i); 
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`startActivityForResult` is used when you have to return some value/data to the first screen like a user selection. More [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

As far as the context to use `getActivity()` or `getApplicationContext()`, I prefer to use the context of current activity `MainActivity.this` its more straitforward similar to [documentation example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#StartActivity)

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Inside a fragment use `getSherlockActivity()` instead of `getActivity()` as `getActivity()` can cause crashes to older devices.

Of course `getApplicationContext()` would always work and not crash but I feel that it may mess the garbage collector and do not let activities to be cleared (but not sure about it)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `startActivityForResult`

Comment: in `startActivityForResult(...)` where is `getActivity()` coming from..?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'right' way. The Github code doesn't first declare the variable. The onther does. I believe for a menu, you normally need to declare the Intent as a local variable, if not a field.

Answer (score 0):

Create an intent: `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateGistActivity.class);`
where `MainActivity` is the activity you're in, and `CreateGistActivity` is the class you want to launch.

Then use `startActivity(Intent)` to launch the new activity: `startActivity(i);`

Or just combine them:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateGistActivity.class));
```

**Full code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
 ....

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.create) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateGistActivity.class);  
        startActivity(i);          

        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`startActivityForResult` probably isn't needed in your case, unless you're expecting to send values between the classes.